# Rails Logging In Users from Non Bcrypt Database

Tags: php, android, ruby-on-rails, md5, bcrypt

So I'm trying to connect my Rails app to a pre-existing database that is already full of users whose passwords were just encrypted with standard encryption and not Bcrypt. The idea is that there is already a working Android application (that uses this database... but not Bcrypt) and my client wants a web version of this application using all the data that's currently in the database.

The problem that we've foreseen is that while I'm sure (I think...) that Rails should have no problem reading the sha-encrypted passwords in the User database... any new user created with the Rails application will have their passwords Bcrypted and the concern is that the existing Android application won't be able to decode those passwords at the login password verification.

So here is how passwords are currently handled in the Rails application:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
validates :password, :confirmation => true
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.encrypted_password= BCrypt::Password.create(password)
    end
  end
```

And then the Android application is encrypted with a simple md5 in the php:

**registration.php**

```
$pass = md5($pass);
```

So the question is... What's the best way to handle this situation?  Do I just encrypt all of the android passwords with Bcrypt and program it to use Bcrypt encryption? Or is there a way (since the Rails application currently has no users of its own) to simply encrypt the new users created in the Rails application with md5?

How would you handle this situation from a coding perspective?

Comment: At this point MD5 is considered insecure and should NOT be used for securing passwords.  https://www.section.io/engineering-education/what-is-md5/ Migrating the android app to use Bcrypt would be path I would take.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. But how would you go about doing it? Remember this i a live Android app... So would I just bcrypt the encrypted passwords or what?

Comment: two columns -- old_password, bcrypt_password.  Send existing users notification through the app that they have to create a new password.  Authenticate using old password, have users create new password which you will bcrypt.  If users have a bcrypt_password -- only allow that to be used for authentication going forward.